# Remove the "programs" bookmark from chrome

Tags: google-chrome, bookmarks

I suddenly got a new bookmark called "Programs" (or apps? "Programmer" in Norwegian either way). How do I remove this?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Just figured it out: Right click the bookmarks bar and uncheck "Show the apps shortcut"